# Получение размера зависимого (привязанного) android виджета

Tags: android, activity, eclipse, view

Как получить текущие размеры виджета например кнопки (Button) или (Surface) в программе (коде) у которого в полях xml файла width height стоит wrap_content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
view.getWidth();
view.getHeight();
```

Comment: это будет работать, если view уже отрисовалось

Comment: а как принудительно его отрисовать ?? мне нада как раз узнать размер до отрисовки

Comment: в общем я пришел к тому что, до прорисовки невозможно получить размеры, поэтому я беру их при первой прорисовке!

Answer (score 0):

```
contentview.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
int width = contentview.getMeasuredWidth();
int height = contentview.getMeasuredHeight();
```

Comment: нули возвращает